# Redirect to Login page after session expired in SessionListenerAdapter

Tags: shiro

I´m using Apache Shiro. I would like to redirect my user to the "login" page, after a session has been expired.

I´ve tried the following code, but the redirect is not working.
I got a NPE:

> Error while validating the session: java.lang.NullPointerException

for the line:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler()
                .handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, /login.xhtml);
```

Here my code:

```
public class MySessionListener2 extends SessionListenerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void onExpiration(Session session) {

        System.out.println("会Session expiration：" + session.getId());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler()
                .handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, Constants.LOGIN);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
04:12:52,177 ERROR [org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.ExecutorServiceSessionValidationScheduler] (SessionValidationThread-1) Error while validating the session: java.lang.NullPointerException
at deployment.myapp.war//com.myapp.util.MySessionListener1.onExpiration(MySessionListener1.java:58)
at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractNativeSessionManager.notifyExpiration(AbstractNativeSessionManager.java:208)
at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager.onExpiration(AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java:157)
at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager.onExpiration(DefaultWebSessionManager.java:284)
at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager.validate(AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java:145)
at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager.validateSessions(AbstractValidatingSessionManager.java:288)
at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.ExecutorServiceSessionValidationScheduler.run(ExecutorServiceSessionValidationScheduler.java:120)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace.  It's hard to tell what the NPE is associated with, without it.

Comment: I can also not Inject a Bean in the Listener class without get a NPE? I guess this is the same as it´s not working for FacesContext ?

Comment: @BrianDemers I´ve updated the Stacktrace

Comment: Looks like something is null in your code?  what is on line 58 in `com.myapp.util.MySessionListener1` ?

Comment: it was mentioned in my first post: ```FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler()
                .handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, /login.xhtml);```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Shiro.  I'm guessing you just need to figure out which one of those objects is `null`.  My goto is use a debugger and inspect the objects.  But you may just want to clean up your code and not chain so many method calls together (which will make it easier to debug).

Comment: In general the question is: can I use ```FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler()                 .handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, /login.xhtml);``` in the SessionListenerAdapter from Shiro?

Comment: Which object in that chain is null?